# Average of marks in examinations

Tags: mean

Is it statistically correct to find out final marks of a student in a paper by taking arithmetic mean only of 4 valuations of a single paper without an answer key, or any rectification measures for the outlier marks?

For eg. Marks obtained by Candidate in 4 valuations are 43, 45, 48 and 51 in a single paper in 4 different valuations. Final marks awarded by taking average of these 4 are 47. Is this method scientifically and statistically correct in an examination?

Comment: how is the question related to clustering? I have removed the cluster tag. And if you still think its related to clustering then elaborate further on this question to specify how its related to clustering. Exercise caution when adding tags. Don't just arbitarily add tags.

Comment: Any objective scheme you can think can be given a rationale. I think of reasons for choosing the student's best mark, worst mark, median mark and mean mark. I don't think scientific or statistical correctness enters. It's how you want to summarize.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the site! Mean, mode, and median are all among many valid measures of [central tendency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_tendency).

Here is a good [link](https://statistics.laerd.com/statistical-guides/measures-central-tendency-mean-mode-median.php) that explains how some of these compare and in what situations it makes sense to use one over the other.

Comment: Why limit the options to these three?  There are infinitely many possible measures of central tendency and many others are in common use.  For instance, Winsorized means are often used in sports competitions that require subjective evaluations.

Comment: @whuber I have heard of trimming in summarizing judges’ scores, but never Winsorizing. Does anyone know of review references for robust measures outside statistics and science, e.g. in sports? My favourite such reference is that the trimmed mean is mentioned in Jules Verne’s _Twenty Thousand Leagues Under The Sea_.

Comment: @Nick Sorry; I did mean mere trimming.  Winsorizing is relatively obscure.